# Calculating distances between multiple sources and targets using pgRouting

Tags: distance, shortest-path

I'm using Postgres/PostGIS/pgRouting to prepare a dataset for an analysis I am doing. One field in the dataset that I need to prepare is the shortest road distance between a dataset of 100,000 households (point data) and a dataset of several dozen activity centres (also point data). I have created a node and network dataset in preparation of this. I have also updated my household and activity_centre datasets with columns holding the id values of the nearest nodes.

So far I have been able to use the driving_distance() function to calculate the road distance from the central business district (CBD) to every household, but I wish to do this for all centres in one run and not have to make separate distance datasets for each centre.

What's more is that I will eventually have to do the same for road distances between each household and the nearest train station.

Is there a solution for this?

Many thanks,

Ro

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if I got your problem right. If it is like

- you have 100k households
- a lesser number (may be 1k) of other
  points of interest (activity center, railway station etc.)
- the
  objective is to show the shortest path from/to one of the households
  to/from a point of interest without doing too much run-time
  calculation.
- I am farther assuming that the road data you have is
  directed, i.e. there may be a one-way roads.
- these points do not change too frequently,

then you may try an approach like this:

1. Prepare a directed graph with all 100+1k nodes and roads as edges. The roads will be directed from node to node with weights proportional to their distance.
2. Prepare a reverse graph of the same -i.e. just switch the from and to nodes, keeping the same weights.
3. For each point of interest P, do a Dijkstra which will return the complete predecessor-map (shortest-path-tree as array) of 100+1k points which gives the shortest distance from P to all other points. This is an integer array of 100+1k values.
4. Repeat this on the reverse graph. this will give you a predecessor_map which gives shortest distance to each point of interest P from all other points.
5. Now you have 2 * 1k arrays , each having 100+1k values. With each array you also know the position of the point P in it.

### Run-time calculations:

- To calculate the the shortest path from P to any other point use the first array. Go to the location of the target point on the array, see what is its corresponding value and go to that element on the array, repeat till you have reached P's position.

> *example*: if P is at 7th position and your end point is at 12th position, 
>   go to array element 12 , read its value array_val[12]=10, 
>   now with 10 , say array_val[10]=7 , then your path is 7-10-12.

- Similarly if you do this operation on the second array, then the shortest path will be the path in reverse order, i.e. 12-10-7.

### Observations:

1. Above two steps are much faster to do at run time (milliseconds). You do not need Dijkstra at run-time for these, a .
2. The first time calculation for 2 * 1k shortest path trees should take a total of about 2*1000*0.8 =1600 seconds (on a linux laptop with 4 GB RAM and i5 processor).
3. You may want to use boost-graph directly to do this, however ..

### Using pgrouting:

If you want to use pgrouting you may want to modify boost_wrapper.cpp function boost_dijkstra to return the complete predecessor_map rather than only one shortest path (copy it to path_vect). This will make pgrouting dijkstra always return the shortest path tree rather than only the shortest path. I have not tested this out yet (note that pgrouting internally does an index reordering but this method should give you back your original index ids).